# What's the correct way to use script files from other script files Meteor?

Tags: javascript, include, meteor

According to [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178015/in-meteor-how-can-i-include-a-js-file-in-another-js-file-server-side) and the Meteor documentation, Meteor will automatically include all scripts in a package folder structure recursively with the deepest first. However, when I define a js class in a script in MyProject/sever folder the class is undefined if referenced from a top-level .js file. If I move the class definition to my top-level .js file above the `if (Meteor.isServer)` the class is defined correctly. What am I missing in structuring or including my javascript from external files?

**EDIT:**
The issue is more fundamental than just seeing my js class. I can't call a function or see *anything* in that private namespace that meteor 0.6 creates. Obviously there must be some way to reference stuff defined in another file or large projects wouldn't be possible in meteor.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with meteor 0.6's scoping of js files. Obviously, this is not always what's wanted. On the client, using the client/compatibility folder does the trick, but not on server. Any known workarounds or best practices for this case?

Comment: Is it undefined on the browser or on the server.. If you have a have a file located in the server directory it will only be loaded on the server. If you then reference it in a top level js file that gets loaded on the server and the client it will then be undefined on the client due to the file in /server only being run on the server.

Comment: It's undefined on the server and being referenced inside the if(Meteor.isServer){} block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, this was related to my misunderstanding of javascript's (goofy hack) class declarations and globals. Changing:

```
function ClassFoo(){
   this.bar = function(){}
}
```

to

```
ClassFoo = function ClassFoo(){
   this.bar = function(){}
}
```

fixed it by making ClassFoo global. FWIW, note that `var ClassFoo = ...` will NOT work because it then becomes local to the auto-generated closure's namespace. Gotta love javascript's quirks.